# User that does not have role outlined in RolesAllowed can still invoke method

Tags: java, security

I've created a custom `IdentityStore`, in order to intercept authentication requests and assign roles based on the user.

This is purely POC, not production worthy. And the aim is to not use any Spring methods,  only standard Java API.

The problem, is that when I authenticate as `user`/`abc123`, calling the method `shoppingCartService.getOrderList()` does not throw an exception even though `user` does not have the `ADMIN` role .. why is that?

Custom `IdentityStore`:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class TestIdentityStore implements IdentityStore {

    public CredentialValidationResult validate(UsernamePasswordCredential usernamePasswordCredential) {

        if (usernamePasswordCredential.compareTo("user", "abc123")) {
            return new CredentialValidationResult("user", new HashSet<>(asList("CUSTOMER")));
        } else if (usernamePasswordCredential.compareTo("admin", "abc123")) {
            return new CredentialValidationResult("admin", new HashSet<>(asList("ADMIN")));
        }

        return INVALID_RESULT;
    }
}
```

ApplicationConfig:

```
@BasicAuthenticationMechanismDefinition(
        realmName = "file"
)
@ApplicationScoped
@Named
public class ApplicationConfig {}
```

Servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/servlet")
@DeclareRoles({ "CUSTOMER", "ADMIN" })
@ServletSecurity(@HttpConstraint(rolesAllowed = {"CUSTOMER", "ADMIN"}))
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String webName = null;
        if (request.getUserPrincipal() != null) {
            webName = request.getUserPrincipal().getName();
        }

        response.getWriter().write("web username: " + webName + "\n");
        response.getWriter().write("web user has role \"CUSTOMER\": " + request.isUserInRole("CUSTOMER") + "\n");
        response.getWriter().write("web user has role \"ADMIN\": " + request.isUserInRole("ADMIN") + "\n");

        ShoppingCartService shoppingCartService = new ShoppingCartServiceImpl();
        try {
            List<OrderItem> items = shoppingCartService.getOrderList();
            response.getWriter().write("shoppingCartService.getOrderList() : " + items + "\n");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.getWriter().write("web user does not have access to shoppingCartService.getOrderList();\n");
        }

        request.logout();
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface ShoppingCartService {

  @RolesAllowed("ADMIN")
  List<OrderItem> getOrderList();
}
```